# Ubuntu, Ngin strange redirect in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, nginx

I have no idea what is happening, but I have an ubuntu server running nginx(port 8000) and apache (port 80) and both pointing the same code base (a rails app).  I am planning on switch to nginx but wanted to test it first.  When i go to my IP address:8000 i get the standard nginx welcome page.  When I go to my rails app (thescotchcabi.net:8000), I get this strange page that seems to be coming from voodoo.com!?!  Here is my nginx log

```
71.232.176.149 - - [08/Mar/2014:15:57:16 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"
71.232.176.149 - - [08/Mar/2014:15:57:17 -0500] "GET /bh.php?dm=thescotchcabi.net&kw=the%20scot%20chc%20abi&tt=dcd95b9c6c601e02013b545d1283984d&ty=false HTTP/1.1" 200 906 "http://www.thescotchcabi.net:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"
71.232.176.149 - - [08/Mar/2014:15:57:17 -0500] "GET /cf.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2051 "http://www.thescotchcabi.net:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"
71.232.176.149 - - [08/Mar/2014:15:57:17 -0500] "GET /cf.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2051 "http://www.thescotchcabi.net:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"
71.232.176.149 - - [08/Mar/2014:15:57:17 -0500] "GET /status.php?tadb=true&domain=thescotchcabi.net HTTP/1.1" 200 38 "http://www.thescotchcabi.net:8000/bh.php?dm=thescotchcabi.net&kw=the%20scot%20chc%20abi&tt=dcd95b9c6c601e02013b545d1283984d&ty=false" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"
71.232.176.149 - - [08/Mar/2014:15:57:18 -0500] "GET /style/960.css HTTP/1.1" 200 893 "http://www.thescotchcabi.net:8000/cf.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"
```

now my first thought was to see where these files were on the system:

```
find / -name 'bh.php'
```

but I got nothing.  So it seems my server is serving up remote files somehow. Here is my nginx conf:

```
server {

            listen 8000 default_server deferred;
            root /var/www/scotchapp/current/public;
            server_name thescotchcabi.net www.thescotchcabi.net;
            index index.htm index.html;

            location ^~ /assets/ {
                    gzip_static on;
                    expires max;
                    add_header Cache-Control public;
            }

            try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
            location @unicorn {
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
            }

            error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
            client_max_body_size 20M;
            keepalive_timeout 10;
    }
```

You can check this out and compare thescotchcabi.net and thescotchcabi.net:8000.  I really don't understand how this can be happening.

Thanks

EDIT: I also found this site http://urlquery.net/report.php?id=9782298 which show the calling of some of the same assets and seem to be related

EDIT: Here is the output of netstat as well.  port 8000 is clearly running.

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 localhost:59231         *:*                     LISTEN      32092/erinmadore
tcp        0      0 *:8000                  *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 *:imaps                 *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 localhost:43715         *:*                     LISTEN      31372/joshuawilcox
tcp        0      0 *:pop3s                 *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 *:8100                  *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 localhost:9000          *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 *:submission            *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 *:pop3                  *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 *:imap2                 *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    localhost:50607         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 localhost:50607         localhost:postgresql    ESTABLISHED 31372/joshuawilcox
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    localhost:48774         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 joshuawilcox.net:imaps  c-71-232-176-149.:38385 ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 joshuawilcox.net:http   static.135.77.63.:54303 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 joshuawilcox.net:imap2  c-71-232-176-149.:35784 ESTABLISHED 863/imap
tcp        0      0 localhost:48775         localhost:postgresql    ESTABLISHED 29189/unicorn.rb -E
tcp        0    672 joshuawilcox.net:ssh    c-71-232-176-149.:45730 ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 localhost:48774         localhost:postgresql    ESTABLISHED     29191/unicorn.rb -E
tcp        0      0 joshuawilcox.net:imaps  c-71-232-176-149.:36705 ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 joshuawilcox.net:imap2  c-71-232-176-149.:35721 ESTABLISHED 450/imap
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    localhost:48775         ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imaps              [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pop3s              [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 [::]:submission         [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pop3               [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imap2              [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 [::]:smtp               [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
```

Comment: try to ping your domain and confirm it's the correct IP

Comment: The when I ping thescotchcabi.net (the one that works fine) it return the proper IP, I cant ping an address with a port thought